# WPF Cross Thread Object Access

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have an issue regarding cross thread calls in WPF.

```
            foreach (RadioButton r in StatusButtonList)
        {
            StatusType status = null;
            r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() => status= ((StatusButtonProperties)r.Tag).StatusInformation));
            if (AppLogic.CurrentStatus == null || AppLogic.CurrentStatus.IsStatusNextLogical(status.Code))
            {
                SolidColorBrush green = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(102, 255, 102));
                r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() =>  r.Background = green));
            }
            else
            {
                SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
                r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() => r.Background = red));
            }
        }
```

When I run this code, it works correctly for the first iteration. However during the second iteration the line:

```
  r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() => status= ((StatusButtonProperties)r.Tag).StatusInformation))
```

Causes this exception:

```
Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.
```

I've tried a few solutions but I can't find anything workable.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Creating SolidColorBrush red + green in a thread which is not the same as r.Dispatcher.Invoke...?

Comment: Why are you using a new thread for those setters? Since you are using Invoke(), it is blocking until that thread is finished with its work, so it probably slows the whole thing down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rewrite this to:

```
r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
{
    status = ((StatusButtonProperties)r.Tag).StatusInformation;

    if (AppLogic.CurrentStatus == null || AppLogic.CurrentStatus.IsStatusNextLogical(status.Code))
    {
        r.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        r.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

}));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    r.Dispatcher.Invoke(
      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new Action(
        delegate()
        {
                // DO YOUR If... ELSE STATEMNT HERE
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are in a different thread than the one which created those RadioButtons. Otherwise the invoking makes no sense. Since you are creating the SolidColorBrush in that thread, you already have a potential cross-thread call there.

It would make more sense to make the cross-thread calls more "chunky", i.e. put everything in the foreach loop in a single Invoke call.

```
foreach (RadioButton r in StatusButtonList)
{
    r.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() => 
        {
            StatusType status = ((StatusButtonProperties)r.Tag).StatusInformation;
            if (AppLogic.CurrentStatus == null || AppLogic.CurrentStatus.IsStatusNextLogical(status.Code))
            {
                SolidColorBrush green = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(102, 255, 102));
                r.Background = green;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
                r.Background = red;
            }
        });
}
```

You could also consider using `BeginInvoke` if the different calls are not interdependant.